# Проверка отображения блока в видимости экрана при скролле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Такая проблема, есть элемент с классом item где-то на странице, не могу понять, как написать код, который будет проверять, есть ли элемент в области экрана при скролле страницы. https://jsfiddle.net/jL42z5n3/

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: purple;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Update: функция желательно на jquery, потому что на странице будет несколько элементов, которые нужно ловить в области экрана и у них есть один общий класс.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
function elementInViewport(el){
    var bounds = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        (bounds.top + bounds.height > 0) && // Елемент ниже верхней границы
        (window.innerHeight - bounds.top > 0) && // Выше нижней
        (bounds.left + bounds.width > 0) && // Правее левой
        (window.innerWidth - bounds.left > 0)// Левее правой
    );
}


document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
    var el = document.querySelector("#thisElement");
    var inViewport = elementInViewport(el);
    document.querySelector("#status").innerText = inViewport ? "Елемент в поле зрения" : "Елемент не в поле зрения";
})
```

```css
p.li{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ffc000;
}

#thisElement{
    background-color: #000000;
}

#status{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<span id="status"></span>
<p class="li"></p>
<p class="li"></p>
<p class="li"></p>
<p class="li"></p>
<p class="li"></p>
<p class="li"></p>
<p class="li" id="thisElement"></p>
<p class="li"></p>
<p class="li"></p>
<p class="li"></p>
<p class="li"></p>
<p class="li"></p>
```